# Are longer titles better? calling SQL magicians

Tags: discussion

I had always thought that a short, succinct title was best for getting attention. But a recent look at Super User, say, showed that longer titles seem to get more attention (especially SU). Same for [a lot](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) of global questions.

Can someone do some SQL magic and some hardcore stats to relate title length to popularity/likedness?

Answer (score 3):

[This has been done before](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.6876v1.pdf), all academic like, even.

[Here is a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/academic-papers-using-stack-exchange-data) to a list of Papers written about Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about *SQL magic* or *hardcore stats*, but [here's a data.SE query I just whipped up](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/209976/title-length-vs-views-vs-score).

It show's the (lack of) correlation between title lengths, votes and views.

[image]

**Note** the "crazy" that erupts around titles of length 150 or more and 15 or less is because there's so few of them, which skew/distort/screw up (can you tell I'm not a mathematician?) the results.

Comment: I guess you and me [were on the same train of thought](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/209969/273559/#graph).

Comment: @gunr2171: Great minds think alike ;). At least our results are similar, which makes me more confident that I haven't screwed anything up :P